# Lennox air conditioner won't cool

Tags: air-conditioning

My Lennox air conditioner is not coming on? When I put the thermostat in cool mode, the outside unit comes on but the inside fan doesn't start!! If I set it to the off position, the inside fan will run but only in manual mode and not on auto!! When I flip the switch to heat, everything works properly!!

Comment: What model is your furnace/air-handler (indoor unit), and can you post photos of the wiring diagram that should be posted somewhere on its insides? What happens if you put the thermostat in COOL mode and then set the inside fan ON? (Don't leave it this way, as you'll get condensate slingout at the end of cycle that will impair or cripple your air conditioner's ability to dehumidify)

Comment: I'll have to check the model and TRY to post pics of the wiring but when I put the thermostat in cool, you can hear the outside unit kick in and start working but the fan won't work in either auto OR manual!! Is there a way to bypass the control board to start the fan just to see if it's the control board that's the problem? Thanks

Comment: the model is C33-COD-2F?

Comment: That's the model number of the evaporator coil, can you get me the model number and/or wiring diagram of the furnace that coil's attached to?

Comment: I have a guy working on it!! He thinks it's a diode on the control panel? whatever that means lol, thank you!!

Comment: Are the batteries in the thermostat good? A diode would be an unusual failure, not impossible, can you send a photo of the board.  Diodes are an easy device to test.

Comment: We're up and running!! Thanks guys!!

Comment: had to change out the control board!!

Comment: @puzzled -- post what the HVAC dude found as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Comment: the relay in the control board was weak is what he said? He put another control board in it and everything is working like it's supposed to!!